# Addition using cobol and loops

Tags: cobol

I am attempting to perform simple addition, but I'm not sure how to do this in cobol. I would like to add the last four years of tuition to a variable total_tuition. However, it will only add this once my first loop has been completed, hence giving me an addition of the last years tuition 4 times (which is not what I want). I completed the task in python to help clarify what I am trying to accomplish. Thank you!

```
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 tuition pic 9(5)v99.
   01 increase pic 9(5)v99 value 00000.05. 
   01 final_tuition pic 9(5)v99. 
   01 total_tuition pic 9(5)v99 value 00000.00. 
   01 temp pic 9(7)v99.
   01 num pic 9 value 1. 
   
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MAIN-PROCEDURE. 
       display 'Please enter the tuition amount: '. 
       accept tuition. 
       
       perform aLoop 10 times.
       display 'Tuition after 10 years is: $', final_tuition. 
       perform bLoop with test after until num > 6. 

       display '4-year tuition in 10 years is: $', total_tuition. 
   STOP RUN.
       aLoop. 
           multiply tuition by increase giving temp . 
           add temp to tuition giving final_tuition. 
           set tuition to final_tuition.
       bLoop. 
           add final_tuition to total_tuition giving total_tuition. 
           add 1 to num. 
           display total_tuition.
```

Python working solution:

```
n = 0
tuition = 10000
increase = .05
temp = 0
total = 0
final = 0
i = 0
while n < 10 : 
    temp = increase * tuition 
    final = tuition + temp
    tuition = final
    if n >= 6: 
        total = final + total 
        print(i, ") total", total)
        i = i + 1
    n = n+1 
print(final, total)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: @IMSoP question was edited and is _now_ very clear - I suggest to delete the comment and close vote.

Comment: @SimonSobisch I have not voted to close, so can't retract that. I believe if nobody else votes to close, the vote will expire, so it doesn't really matter anyway. I would dispute "very clear" though, since as you point out in a comment below, the Python version doesn't have two loops, which the text of the question implies are essential.

Comment: Seems that the given answer solved your issue - please mark it as "accepted" in this case to not have this question in the "answered but not solved" list. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Python version, you have an if statement. In the COBOL version, you have a second loop.

Try this code:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. HELLO-WORLD.
   DATA DIVISION.
   
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 tuition pic 9(5)v99 value 10000.
   01 increase pic 9(5)v99 value 00000.05. 
   01 final_tuition pic 9(5)v99. 
   01 total_tuition pic 9(5)v99 value 00000.00.
   01 temp pic 9(7)v99.
   01 num pic 9 value 0. 
   
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MAIN-PROCEDURE.              
       perform aLoop 10 times.
       display 'Tuition after 10 years is: $', final_tuition.     
       display '4-year tuition in 10 years is: $', total_tuition. 
   STOP RUN.
       aLoop. 
            multiply tuition by increase giving temp . 
            add temp to tuition giving final_tuition. 
            set tuition to final_tuition.
            if num >= 6 then
                add final_tuition to total_tuition giving total_tuition
            end-if
            add 1 to num.
```

Output

```
Tuition after 10 years is: $16288.91
4-year tuition in 10 years is: $60647.68
```

Comment: It is even more different - the python version has a _nested_ if, while the COBOL version has the "unrelated" loop.

Comment: @SimonSobisch Like I stated. I just started learning COBOL and I'm trying to figure out the functionality of it lol.